# Copy audio stream, while also re-encoding with filters?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, matroska

I'm using this command to copy the video & audio streams while also encoding the first audio stream to a stereo AAC track as well:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mkv -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 copy -map 0:a:0? -c:a:1 aac -b:a:0 192k -ac 2 -map 0:a:1? -c:a:2 copy -map 0:a:2? -c:a:3 copy -map 0:a:3? -c:a:4 copy out.mkv
```

However, I'm also wanting to filter that stereo track with better channel mapping like so:

```
-af "pan=stereo|FL=FC+0.25*FL+0.60*LFE|FR=FC+0.20*FR+0.60*LFE"
```

But when I try that I get the following error:

```
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.
```

Is there any way around that error? As I'd like to have the original audio stream in tact, while also encoding another version to a 'nightmode' stereo track.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0? -map 0:a:0? -map 0:a:1? -map 0:a:2? -map 0:a:3? -c copy -filter:a:1 "pan=stereo|FL=FC+0.25*FL+0.60*LFE|FR=FC+0.20*FR+0.60*LFE" -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 192k -ac 2 out.mkv
```

`-af` is short for `-filter:a` which applies to all output audio streams. Add a stream number to qualify the application.